Virtual environment created with pipx - update python version
I have package installed with command:
pipx install package
Now I need:

update Python version installed on server (this can be done eaisly by apt command
update Python version inside existing virtual environment, created automatically by pipx when installing my package
upgrade package - above steps are required, because new version of my package requires higher Python version

Can you advice what is correct walkthrough to do that? I want to be safe, in case when anything fails, I need to be able to restore previous state (current package version working fine on current Python version).
My OS is Debian Testing.

Here are the steps to refactor the pipx uninstall process for my-package to preserve data and settings:

Locate the pipx data directory for my-package
By default, pipx stores package data in:
~/.local/pipx/venvs/my-package

Confirm this directory contains the data and settings you want to preserve.

Rename the data directory
Before uninstalling, rename the directory to prevent it from being deleted:
mv ~/.local/pipx/venvs/my-package ~/.local/pipx/venvs/my-package-data

This moves the data to a new directory called my-package-data.

Uninstall my-package
Proceed with the uninstall:
pipx uninstall my-package

This will remove the package and virtual environment, but the data is preserved in the renamed directory.

Reinstall my-package
Install a fresh version of the package:
pipx install my-package

A new virtual environment will be created at ~/.local/pipx/venvs/my-package.

Restore the data
Copy the preserved data back to the package directory:
cp -r ~/.local/pipx/venvs/my-package-data/* ~/.local/pipx/venvs/my-package/

This restores your original data and settings to the new installation.

Clean up (optional)
Once you've confirmed the package is working properly with the restored data, you can remove the backup data directory:
rm -rf ~/.local/pipx/venvs/my-package-data



By following these steps, pipx uninstall my-package will leave your original data and settings untouched. You can then restore them after reinstalling the package.
The Python update steps you provided are relevant if you also need to change the Python version used by the package. Just make sure to use the --python option when re-running pipx install to specify the desired Python interpreter.
If your still having issues, just leave further feedback in the comments.

pipx uninstall my-package - won't it erase my-package data and settings?

You're right, uninstalling the package with pipx uninstall my-package will remove the package and its associated virtual environment, including any data and settings specific to that package.

@user1209216 I went ahead and refactored my original answer to address your comment.

Thanks. Last (I think) question. In case when something went wrong. There will be 2 Python versions, older inside venv and higher version globally. Isn't it any problem?

It is possible to have two different versions of Python installed on your computer - one globally and one within a virtual environment. This setup won't create any issues because each virtual environment works independently of the others. Therefore, the Python version installed within a virtual environment won't interfere with the global version, and vice versa. Youtup to manage di can use this sefferent Python versions for different projects without any conflicts. In case of any problems, you can troubleshoot each environment separately without impacting the others.

Will pipx reinstall-all delete all packages data? Or only Python upgraded and data will be preserved? Looking at pipx docs, it says reinstall is unistall + install again, so literally it's going to delete package data? It's not mentioned in their docs
